# javafx.fxml.LoadException:

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

so I'm getting this error message about an fmxl file, it says:

```
Dec 29, 2021 2:11:16 P.M. javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 17 by JavaFX runtime of version 16
Dec 29, 2021 2:11:16 P.M. javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 17 by JavaFX runtime of version 16
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/georg/OneDrive%20-%20Waterford%20Institute%20of%20Technology/semester-3/datastruc-alg-1/dsaAsgnOne/target/classes/dsaasgnone/dsaasgnone/AddApp.fxml:13
/C:/Users/georg/OneDrive%20-%20Waterford%20Institute%20of%20Technology/semester-3/datastruc-alg-1/dsaAsgnOne/target/classes/dsaasgnone/dsaasgnone/Main.fxml:33

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1156)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:756)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at dsaasgnone.dsaasgnone/dsaasgnone.dsaasgnone.App.start(App.java:75)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "appointments" because "dsaasgnone.dsaasgnone.App.store" is null
    at dsaasgnone.dsaasgnone/dsaasgnone.dsaasgnone.Controllers.AddAppController.<init>(AddAppController.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:938)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:982)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:229)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application dsaasgnone.dsaasgnone.App
```

I've mainly been trying to solve the problem by trying to fix this part here (then again, I may be completely wrong about this)

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/georg/OneDrive%20-%20Waterford%20Institute%20of%20Technology/semester-3/datastruc-alg-1/dsaAsgnOne/target/classes/dsaasgnone/dsaasgnone/AddApp.fxml:13
/C:/Users/georg/OneDrive%20-%20Waterford%20Institute%20of%20Technology/semester-3/datastruc-alg-1/dsaAsgnOne/target/classes/dsaasgnone/dsaasgnone/Main.fxml:33
```

Main.fxml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="419.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
   <children>
      <TabPane prefHeight="411.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
            <Tab text="Welcome">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="407.0" prefWidth="600.0">
                     <children>
                        <fx:include source="SaveController.fxml" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Add Patient">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <fx:include source="AddPatient.fxml" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
          <Tab text="Make Appointment">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <fx:include source="AddApp.fxml" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Appointment List">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <fx:include source="AppList.fxml" />
                     </children></AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
            <Tab text="Add Vaccine Centre">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <fx:include source="AddVc.fxml" />
                     </children></AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Add Booth">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <fx:include source="AddBooth.fxml" />
                     </children></AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Edit Centre/Booth">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <fx:include source="EditBoothVc.fxml" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Line 33 in Main.fmxl is just

```
<fx:include source="AddApp.fxml" />
```

so I don't believe that's the problem.

AddApp.fxml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
            prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="dsaasgnone.dsaasgnone.Controllers.AddAppController">
   <Button fx:id="confirm" layoutX="252.0" layoutY="305.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addApp"
           text="Make Booking"/>
   <DatePicker fx:id="appDate" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="49.0"/>
   <ChoiceBox fx:id="appTime" layoutX="358.0" layoutY="49.0" prefWidth="150.0"/>
   <ComboBox fx:id="appVc" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="114.0" prefWidth="150.0"/>
   <ComboBox fx:id="appBooth" layoutX="358.0" layoutY="114.0" prefWidth="150.0"/>
   <TextField fx:id="appPpsn" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="187.0"/>
   <Label layoutX="62.0" layoutY="32.0" text="Select Date"/>
   <Label layoutX="358.0" layoutY="32.0" text="Select Time"/>
   <Label layoutX="62.0" layoutY="97.0" text="Select Vaccine Centre"/>
   <Label layoutX="358.0" layoutY="97.0" text="Select Booth"/>
   <Label layoutX="224.0" layoutY="169.0" text="Enter PPSN"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

Line 13 of AddApp.fxml is

```
fx:controller="dsaasgnone.dsaasgnone.Controllers.AddAppController">
```

so I also don't understand why that's an error.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of the code are below:
[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woX6L.png)

[Line 13 of AddApp.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGJhZ.png)

[Line 33 of Main.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDMi5.png)

Comment: Post the complete stack trace, not just the snippet you have.

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit: you have a Null Pointer Exception on line 25 of `AddAppController` because `store` is null. If that's not enough information to solve the problem, you need to post the relevant code.